# selenium rc server does not exit after running an htmlsuite

Tags: selenium

Am I missing something obvious? The docos state that:

```
-htmlSuite    : Run a
    single HTML Selenese (Selenium Core) suite and then exit
    immediately ...
```

but my instance doesn't seem to (it also doesn't write to the html output either)

I am running : java -jar /opt/selenium-server-1.0.3/selenium-server.jar -debug -htmlSuite *googlechrome http://www.google.co.uk ~/tsg1.ts ~/g.out

I have also given up trying to put xml into this editor - but all I am doing is opening www.google.co.uk and looking for "about google" - which works fine in the firefox ide, but never exits on RC... Any ideas ?! The same happens with *firefox as well :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok - I dug around and found the following.

The selenium IDE generates an ERRONEOUS line in the "heading" which somehow breaks the -htmlsuite option (ie it never exits). Comment the line out as per this example : 
`

< table id="suiteTable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1" class="selenium" >

< tbody >

**< !-- < tr >< td >< b > Test Suite< / b >< /td >< /tr > -- >**

< tr >< td >< a href="test_case_google" >test_case_google< /a >< /td >< /tr >

< /tbody >< /table >

< /body >

< /html >
`

Comment: I just ran across this issue, so thanks for the answer.  I'm curious why this would break selenium though.  I don't see anything wrong with this HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Try with quotes:

```
java -jar /opt/selenium-server-1.0.3/selenium-server.jar -debug -htmlSuite '*googlechrome" "http://www.google.co.uk" "~/tsg1.ts" "~/g.out"
```

Answer (score 1):

I only have this problem with firefox. Running with chrome seems to work fine.

If you do what Richard Green suggests you only get to run one test (the last one it seems). The "Test Suite" line tells selenium that it is a test suite and needs to run all the tests present.

So the problem seems to be that in firefox at least it wont jump from test to test when running a test suite.

For firefox if you do what is described in this issue: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1759 it works. Chrome works too.

If by any chance the link doesn't work the workaround is to remove the first two lines of the files:

> ... yanked out the first two lines of each file.  The ones starting with:
>      xml version...
>      DOCTYPE html PUBLIC...

Answer (score 0):

You "**must**" save all your html test with "**.html**" extension and reference them in testSuit.html with the ".html" extension.

So, instead of:

```
    <table id="suiteTable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1" class="selenium">
    <tbody>
    <tr><td><b>Test Suite</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="test_case_google">test_case_google</a></td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

It "**must**" be:

```
    <table id="suiteTable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" border="1" class="selenium">
    <tbody>
    <tr><td><b>Test Suite</b></td></tr>
    <tr><td><a href="test_case_google.html">test_case_google</a></td></tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```